# Song from The Naked Gun?

Tags: identify-this-song, rock

There is a music played in *The Naked Gun* by a band almost at the end. I know that its a rock n roll song and I think that Bruce Springsteen covers it. Can anyone tell me whats its name?

Comment: You got a link to a clip so we can all see it?

Comment: https://youtu.be/JnI30mIKW2k?t=76

I found one! Its the song played by that band.

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095705/soundtrack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ["Louie Louie,"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4V1p1dM3snQ) originally performed by The Kingsmen. It's a really common piece played by pep and marching bands these days, as shown in the video.